# How will you organize your folder structure in .net/Problem which we are facing

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, build-automation, coding-style

We have divided our folder structure into **Client tier and the server side**( WPF front end
and WCF server side) divide by the solution folders . But both lie under a **same solution** .The projects has increased a lot and now we have around 22 projects in the same solution . **Even for a normal build it takes ages**.. How can i avoid this problem .

I suggusted dividing the solution into server and client But team wants to debug so they are not ready . so need a solution which also solves the debugging issue. Or is there any particular guidance for organizing the correct folder structure for the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create several solutions.

One that includes all projects, and one for client development that includes only the projects needed for client development, etc.

All solutions are in the same "root" folder. That's easier for adding projects and version control.

Project can "belong" to multiple solutions, as long as the references to other projects exist in the same solution.

The only thing you have to remember is to add a new project to all the concerning solutions.

For example, we have the following solutions

- *Main* - contains all, also includes the installation project, and projects that are only needed during installation
- *Client* - contains only the client (Windows Forms)
- *Test* - About the same as the client, but with test projects
- *Debug* - actually one project per developper, mostly a copy from Client (or Test), with projects removed for faster builds during development / debugging cycles

Comment: If your working/debugging both the client & the server at the same time you need both, but maybe not all modules need to be debuggable, and you can just reference the .Dll and not the project. This increases build times.